# How to navigate from mainwindow.xaml to page.xaml in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I know how to navigate from one "page.xaml" to another "page.xaml" using

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but I need code to navigate from main "window.xaml" to "page.xaml".

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `Page` which is displayed before any other pages into your `Frame`. Then the usual navigation can occur.

Here is XAML example which should stay in your `Window.xaml`:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Frame Name="LeftNavigationFrame"
           Grid.Column="0" >
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

And in your .xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }
    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LeftNavigationFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(...));
    }
}
```

If you would like, here is another option, using `App.xaml.cs`, your main entry point for application. Navigating to first page is done in `OnLaunched` method and you should already have this method there if the project was created with Visual Studio New Project wizards.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {                
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // Here you can navigate to some other pages if saved some sort of state
            }                
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Replace MainPage with your desire page
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }

        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```